# is the latest mongodb 4.2 just released is a stable new version?

Tags: mongodb

i found on https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/r4.2.0, it is released.

i know, that even versions are the stable versions, so, should i start using it?

i can build it with my github repo, but i am on the 4.0.12...

https://github.com/patrikx3/docker-debian-testing-mongodb-stable

Comment: It's currently a *release candidate*: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's extremely ephemeral and will be useless very soon. Moreover we cannot recommend what version of a software you should or shouldn't use.

Comment: mongodb 4.2 is not rc anymore, it is stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the latest mongodb 4.2 just released as the stable version - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/